# Android Studio: import com.android.volley.xxxx Cannot Resolve Symbol 'xxxx'

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-volley

So, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) to create a `ListView` with images using `Volley` but I am having this issue with the `com.android.volley.xxxx` import statements in `LruBitmapCache.java`, `AppController.java`, `CustomListAdapter.java`, and `MainActivity.java`. It shows as `Unused import statements` and its extension are in red saying `Cannot resolve symbol xxxx`. `Volley.jar` is already aded to `app -> libs` section.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: have you cleaned the solution and refreshed the project int he package explorer?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you mean by cleaning the project then yes but have not used the rebuild project option yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd double check to make sure your build.gradle includes:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    ...
}
```

And also make sure you've ran a sync.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but now I get the following error when I try to run it `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

Comment: By the way, I have both jdk 1.7.0_45 and 1.8.0_45 installed.

Comment: Hi @w_lpz, Can I ask on how did you solve this issue? I'm currently experiencing it as well although I already have those parts on my build.gradle file,

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6@aar'
```

to your Gradle dependencies...

Comment: When I am adding this the error is gone, but when runt getting this error `Program type already present: com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your build.gradle of your app

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'