# Cannot resolve symbol Request in android studio

Tags: android-volley

I have build the jar file of volley library and I included that in my project's libs folder. Even though I'm getting an error

> cannot symbol request

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
```

please, someone help me..

Comment: try the following link.That may help you.
 < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842997/android-studio-import-com-android-volley-xxxx-cannot-resolve-symbol-xxxx>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are making a child of StringRequest. The child needs to have a constructor super call before the error message will go away. Try it and let me know what happens.